# How do I import and use an async JS function in Kotlin/JS?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-js, kotlin-js-interop

I'm having issues importing a Javascript async function into my Kotlin code.

Here is an example Javascript function :

```
export async function signUp(email, password){

    console.log("Signing Up");

    try {
        const userCred = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        console.log(userCred);

        return userCred.user.accessToken
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

I import it in my Kotlin as such :

```
@JsModule("@jlengrand/firebase-ports")
@JsNonModule
external object FirebasePorts{

    suspend fun signUp(email: String, password: String) : String
}
```

When using the function, I expect to get a String out of it :

```
    var user : String? by mutableStateOf(null)

            Button( attrs = {
                onClick { 
                    GlobalScope.launch {
                        user = FirebasePorts.signUp(email, password)
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("Login!")
            }

            // printing the value
            TextArea(value = user.toString())
```

However, what I get instead is a Promise

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async functions in JS are currently not mapped to suspend functions in Kotlin. To get an async function working in Kotlin, you need to deal with the native promises:

```
import kotlin.js.Promise

@JsModule("@jlengrand/firebase-ports")
@JsNonModule
external object FirebasePorts {

   fun signUp(email: String, password: String) : Promise<String>
}
```

Then use `FirebasePorts.signUp(...).then { ... }` to access the value.

Comment: Yup, that works thanks! Expecting suspend to be mapped to async was clearly a stretch. Thank you!